# I want to know all about encodings

Tags: encoding

I really don't understand anything about encodings.

Also I want to know about the differences between different encodings and how much space does one character take in an encoding? And how do encodings matter? How does it matter to the web browser when sending an HTML? Which is the best encoding to use in web applications made in English? What is ASCII?

It would be good if you can explain starting from the basics.

Comment: what about google it? "encoding algorithm"

Comment: Start with Joel Spolsky's article http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: A **very** worthy goal and definitely something that more people should do. **But** such a broad question is not suited for the SO format. Start with Spolsky's article linked above and continue with [this Wikipedia article on Character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the following books:

- Unicode Explained, [http://www.amazon.com/Unicode-Explained-Jukka-K-Korpela/dp/059610121X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059610121X)
- Fonts & Encodings, [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0596102429/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102429)

You can also check out the following free e-books (currently in draft version) that provide lots of information about encoding and multi-lingual text processing:

- LingPipe and Text Processing Books,
  http://alias-i.com/lingpipe-book/index.html